# If $f(x) $ is a continuous function with a given identity, how do I find $f(\sqrt{3})$?

Tags: calculus, functions, functional-equations

> If $f(x) $ Is a continuous function $   \forall\ x \in R$  and satisfies
>   $x^2+x \{f(x)\} - 3 = \sqrt{3} \ f(x)   \  \forall\ x \in R$
>
> Find $f(\sqrt{3})$.

$\{ t\}$ is the fractional part of $t$.

--

My attempt: I substituted $\sqrt{3}$ in that and could only conclude that $0 \leq f(\sqrt{3}) < 1$

Comment: What's the definition of fractional part here?

Comment: @JonatanB.Bastos, if $0\le a\lt1$ then the *integral* part of $a$ is $0$, but the *fractional* part is $a$.

Comment: I think that the fractional part is anything to the right of the decimal not the integer part

Comment: @samjoe But that makes no use of the continuity of $f$, which seems important here.

Comment: @SatishRamanathan, not that it matters to the problem here, but what would you say is the fractional part of $-0.25$?

Comment: I am getting a strange answer using $\lim_{x\to \sqrt 3}$ that is $-2\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Compute $f(0)=-\sqrt{3}$. Observe that $f$ is unbounded from above, since $x^2\to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$. Therefore it has some zero for $x>0$. Let $x_0$ be such that $f(x_0)=0$. Then $x_0^2-3=0$. Therefore $x_0=\sqrt{3}$. So, $f(\sqrt{3})=0$.

Comment: @despaigne, I believe you should add your comment as another answer, as it illustrates a very interesting way to approach the problem. 

A question: do you think we can make your approach work if we assume the equation to hold only in a neighborhood of $\sqrt{3}$ (and not for every $x \in \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @BarryCipra My bad, i was thinking floor function for some reason.

Answer (score 8):

By substituting $\sqrt{3}$ in there, you get that $f(x) - \{f(x)\} = 0$, which implies that $0 \leq a < 1$ as you concluded.

Now suppose $f(\sqrt{3}) = a, 0 < a < 1$. Then, by continuity, $f$ satisfies the equation $x^2 + xf(x) - 3 = \sqrt{3} f(x)$ in a neighborhood of $x = \sqrt{3}$, so that $$f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 3}{\sqrt{3} - x} = -(\sqrt{3} + x),$$

which implies that $f(\sqrt{3}) = - 2\sqrt{3} < 0$ (a contradiction because $a > 0$). Therefore, we must have $f(\sqrt{3}) =0$.

Comment: @samjoe: Sorry, you are correct. The signs got scrambled in my head. I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: No problem just a typo! But can you tell me how we conclude $f(\sqrt 3) = 0$ in the end?

Comment: We know that $0 \leq f(\sqrt{3}) < 1$, and we concluded that we cannot have $f(\sqrt{3}) > 0$ (because we reach a contradiction). Therefore we must have $f(\sqrt{3}) = 0$.

Comment: Note that the argument that $x^2 - xf(x) - 3 = \sqrt{3} f(x)$ in a neighborhood of $\sqrt{3}$ only works if $f(\sqrt{3})$ is strictly greater than zero (so that it is strictly greater than zero in a neighborhood as well).

Comment: @PedroM. Thanks for the answer, but I didn't get why getting $f(\sqrt{3}) < 0$ directly implies it has to be 0.

Comment: @Rick If you assume $f(\sqrt 3) > 0$ only then the equation $x^2 + xf(x) - 3 = \sqrt{3} f(x) $ is true (we simplified $\{f(x)\}$ in original eqn. due to this assumption) Now this assumption implies $f(x) < 0$ (ie $-2\sqrt 3$). So we cannot have $f(x) > 0$, and from your own inequality ($0 \le f(x) < 1$)must have $f(x) = 0$

Comment: @samjoe But that equation $x^2+xf(x)−3=3–f(\sqrt{x})$would also be true if we assumed $a \geq 0 $ and not just $a > 0$

Comment: @Rick Only at $x = \sqrt{3}$, and not *in a neighborhood* of $\sqrt{3}$, and this is the key point. We may have $f(x) < 0$ for some $x$ near $\sqrt{3}$ and the equation does not hold. This is the key point (neighborhood), otherwise the step where we "divide by $\sqrt{3} - x$" doesn't make sense.